# What is this component? I couldn't find the datasheet

Tags: microcontroller, identification

I want to find the datasheet for this component but I couldn't find it.

I was able to find images of it on google but couldn't find any information on what it is.  What I'm interested in is whether this is a passive device or an active device ( microprocessor, eeprom, etc.)

Here is the marking on the chip:

- VM09AE
- 2171.75.001.01

[image]

Here is a link to the [photo of the chip.](http://www.ic-antech.com/uploadfile/electronic-components/uploadpics/201205/20120512102406491.jpg)

Comment: Where does that circuit board come from?

Comment: Search is always the first option: VM09AE Alibaba.

Comment: why are you withholding information? ... you said that you found images on the web ... please add a link to your post

Comment: Chu if you read my post correctly it says i have found images and found where to buy it.but even the seller don't have the datasheet for it.i'm looking for a datasheet to understand what this chip is.

Comment: Jsotola i've added a link to the image of the seller.i found the chip in a speed sensor board.i'm trying to understand what it does specially is it an active components (does it have code in it)

Comment: It could be said that a resistive array might have 16 or more pins, but I consider it highly unlikely that a passive SOP component would require 16 pins.
You could help who is trying to help you by saying us what is the circuit where you found it, and what other components are on the same PCB. You could do a little reverse-engineering and from the wiring diagram you would be able to understand what is the function of that IC is and find who produces it with another P/N code or an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be some form of pentode transistor

https://xinruitrade.en.alibaba.com/product/60753444730-801027370/VM09AE_new_and_original_electronics_component_Integrated_Circuits_new_and_original_electronics_component_Integrated_Circuits.html

Comment: I find that highly unlikely. I have never seen a pentode transistor; though [it seems like they have been experimented with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentode_transistor). If such a thing existed or was used, I'd expect a 5-pin package. This one has 16-pins. I have stumbled upon the page you've linked too looking for it, but I just don't think it's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers and sharing your thoughts.what i want to know is only if this is a programmable chip or just a passive ic that's all i care about if i buy it and solder it and will be ready to go or it has some code then it would be hard for me to use it since it has no datasheet

Comment: If it is some kind of package with a pentode transistor (or multiple) in it, it's passive. But like Richard said, it's very unlikely since these kind of devices are not very common. Can you tell us anything about the circuit / PCB that it's used in?